# samba permissions/ locked out of folders

Tags: samba, ownership

trying to build ubuntu-server fileserver following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4MIWzLwZy8
and
http://quidsup.net/tutorials/?p=ubuntu-create-nas

Raid5 disk & samba

with this in Samba conf file:
edit:(not sure of "user" and "nobody" verbiage. do those need to be an actual username?)

```
#Example smb.conf file
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    load printers = no
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* 
%n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
obey pam restrictions = yes
null passwords = yes
map to guest = Bad User
encrypt passwords = yes
passdb backend = tdbsam
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
dns proxy = no
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
unix password sync = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP
debug level = 1
guest account = nobody
os level = 20
auto services = global
syslog = 0
usershare allow guests = yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
max log size = 1000
pam password change = yes
use sendfile = yes
time server = no
wins support = no


#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
browseable = no
comment = Home Directories
available = no

[music]
comment = music
writeable = yes
store dos attributes = no
path = /mnt/rdisk/music
force create mode = 0755
printable = no
write list = md nobody
inherit acls = yes
public = yes
hide dot files = yes
read list = nobody md
valid users = nobody md
create mask = 0755
inherit permissions = yes
user = nobody md
force directory mode = 0755
directory mask = 0755
ea support = no
```

my fstab for raid device:

```
/dev/md0 /mnt/rdisk ext3 rw,user,auto       0       0
```

also used UUID (no difference)
why would this one entry make two entries in "Disk and Network Filesystems":

```
/ext3 rw,user,auto  0   Partition with ID b930483c-b9f7-4dfb-8740-d3d7ec117d06  
No  Yes
```

(^^notice, not in use)
and

```
/mnt/rdisk  Linux Native Filesystem (ext3)  RAID device 0   5%  Yes     No
```

(^^^in use)
there must be a simple explanation!

anyways, after creating folders in /mnt/rdisk/
i try to take ownership:

```
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ ls
lost+found  music
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo mkdir business
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo mkdir engineering
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo mkdir software
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo mkdir video
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ ls
business  engineering  lost+found  music  software  video
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chmod a=rw -R /mnt/rdisk
[sudo] password for md:
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup music/
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup engineering/
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup business/
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup software/
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup video/
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo chown -hR md:md /mnt/rdisk/
[sudo] password for md:
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ sudo mount -a
[sudo] password for md:
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ ls -dl
ls: cannot access .: Permission denied
md@ubuntuserver:/mnt/rdisk$ ls
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

something about (Edit) having raid mounted locks me out of the folder(s) in terminal and makes shared folders in windows client inaccessible. if i umount, access is restored.

For testing, I've re created a NEW folder structure and not used the above command. It worked until i rebooted, then i found myself locked out again.
not sure what the conflict is / what i'm missing.
so close to done!!!

Answer (score 0):

For directories in Ubuntu you need to have the 'x' labeled in the permissions for directories. even if you own the directory you can still keep yourself out if you forget to add the 'x' for owner. IE chmod 766 would lock you out of the folder if you were not the owner. or chmod +xwr /folder. Another example would be dxwrxwrx-r, would give group and owner read write and access to the directory and everyone else just read access. However, if you drop the 'x' at the end so its dxwrxwr--r, you will lock everyone out of the directory, but owner and group would be good. The -R means its recursive so it does it all the way down, for both files and directories. Use sudo find /var/{directory} -type f -print -exec chmod 664 {} \; to only change the files and not the directories inside the folder. And depending on what you want to do with permissions, I normally do chmod 775 on the directories, and then do the above find for the rest.

sorry to also fix the command you listed, sudo chmod a=rw -R /mnt/rdisk should be sudo chmod a=xrw -R /mnt/rdisk or sudo chmod 775 -R /mnt/rdisk and then use the find function up top to fix the permissions on the files so they all are not executable.

I didn't see the edit originally, trying to find out now, why the folders are disappearing upon restart.

This is another tutorial that seems to be better written with screenshots and explanations, which maybe a bit better. 
https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-ubuntu-14.04-lts
and another helpful one.
http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-file-server-ubuntu-14-04-samba/

Hopefully those help get you over your rough patch.

The document from the website you were looking at. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hFw1YnH9s-1Y9M4VPLgPOOjm1iH6PJOHefg5NhGC4oA/edit?pli=1

I was incorrect, there is no difference between a NAS and a NFS. However, when people talk about NAS they usually mean the systems with multipul drives that can be maintained using a webgui and the like, and NFS is what people normally consider window shares. (this of course is in my experience). So I apologize for getting confused with the nomenclature. The first two sites I listed I think are better written and probably easier to use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35673/discussion-on-answer-by-caperneoignis-samba-permissions-locked-out-of-folders).

Comment: Sorry about that, comments got carried away.